# How do I set the text in an input that works with POST?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following which I want to POST to create when I hit submit.  Only, when I hit submit I get an object reference error referring to my value for the input with id = debugTxt.  I suspect that because I've lost the object state, I get this error.

So my question is how can I set the text with an initial view that comes from the Model and allow the user to update on POST?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "PhysDoc"))
{
    <table>
        <tr>
           <td class="title">Debug Mode</td>
           <td>
                This input does the initial GET correctly.  On POST I get object ref error related to the value inside @Model.
                <input type="text" id="debugTxt" name="debugModeTxt" value="@Model.DebugMode" />
            </td>  
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>                
}
```

Create Method (Note the exception is not thrown here).

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(string debugModeTxt)
    {
        PhysdocSettings settings = new PhysdocSettings();
        settings.DebugMode = bool.Parse(debugModeTxt);
        PhysDocSettingsBL settingBL = new PhysDocSettingsBL();
        settingBL.UpdateSettings(settings);
        return View("Index");
    }
```

The exception occurs here:

`value="@Model.DebugMode"`  and if I change `value="True"` my code works fine.  But this doesn't give me an initial value equal to Model.DebugMode.

Comment: Just to confirm, the model isn't populated correctly with the value you would like to set as the default for the input? If this is the case, then could you please post the code from the controller that calls the view? (You should also consider using @Html.TextBoxFor([lambda expression]) for your text box. Makes mapping easier!

Comment: @levib - not exactly.  Updated quetion

Comment: So your error is in the code of the PhysDoc.Create(), correct? Can you provide the signature of that method?

Comment: @levib - The error is thrown in the View.  `value="@Model.Debug` is where the exception occurs.  It never makes it to the Create().

Comment: please show the ActionResult method that recieves these values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this... Use an HTML helper and specify a default value for the field like so:

```
@Html.TextBox("[name]", @Model.DebugMode)
```

If this doesn't work can you elaborate on the result?

---

You aren't passing a model to Index when you call `return View("Index");`. You are merely calling the view and as such you will indeed get a Null Reference Exception.

Comment: This improved things.  Now the Create method gets called.  But after Create() completes and calls View("Index") I'm right back to the same error regarding this line.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in the code, is debugModeTxt filled with the appropriate data?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that.  debugModeTxt parameter is True like it's supposed to be.  The update works without error.

Comment: Indeed!  Thanks for the help.  This was a pretty annoying bug.  Good job